# apn_on_rails suddenly throws sslv3 alert certificate revoked

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications

Rails: 3.0.5
Ruby: 1.9.2
apn_on_rails: 0.5.1

Suddenly started receiving Exception: "sslv3 alert certificate revoked" from apn_on_rails gem. However the notifications are still sent out to devices and the certificates are valid until 2013.

To Reproduce:

1. rails console.
2. create notification to one of existing devices.

   not1 = APN::Notification.create(:device_id => devices[0].id, :sound => true, :badge => 1, :alert => "Testing")
3. Execute `APN::App.send_notifications`. (Note: APN::Notification.send_notifications is not at all sending any notifications and in turn calls APN::App.send_notifications)

*Expected Output:* Notification to be sent to device. No Exception thrown.

*Actual Output:* Notification sent to device. Exception thrown. Full stack trace of exception below:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > APN::App.send_notifications
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A: sslv3 alert certificate revoked
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A: sslv3 alert certificate revoked
    from /gems/apn_on_rails-0.5.1/lib/apn_on_rails/libs/connection.rb:59:in `connect'
    from /gems/apn_on_rails-0.5.1/lib/apn_on_rails/libs/connection.rb:59:in `open'
    from /gems/apn_on_rails-0.5.1/lib/apn_on_rails/libs/connection.rb:23:in `open_for_delivery'
    from /gems/apn_on_rails-0.5.1/lib/apn_on_rails/app/models/apn/app.rb:48:in `send_notifications_for_cert'
    from /gems/apn_on_rails-0.5.1/lib/apn_on_rails/app/models/apn/app.rb:36:in `send_notifications'
```

Answer (score 1):

As the stack trace indicates - the issue was within /gems/apn_on_rails-0.5.1/lib/apn_on_rails/app/models/apn/app.rb

In App.rb, in method self.send_notifications method:

```
def self.send_notifications
    apps = APN::App.all
    apps.each do |app|
      app.send_notifications
    end
    if !configatron.apn.cert.blank?
      global_cert = File.read(configatron.apn.cert)
      send_notifications_for_cert(global_cert, nil)
    end
end
```

Note: (`if !configatron.apn.cert.blank?`) The code checks for global certificate, whether you have defined this or not, it will check for "config/apple_push_develpment_certification.pem" and send notification with this certificate.

In my case, i had this file "**config/apple_push_develpment_certification.pem**" and i also add two different certificates for my iPhone and iPad apps defined by two configatron variables. Hence i encountered the certificate revoked issue and also my notifications were sent to devices.

To fix this:
define "configatron.apn.cert" to point to your new certificate in development.rb and production.rb files